# requestedExecutionLevel in manifest file and failing CopyFile() function

Tags: c, winapi, uac

Just trying to copy a file using CopyFile() function from the current directory to C:\windows\system32\drivers.

I wrote also manifest with "requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable"" in it and I run mt to add it to resulting executable.

When I try to run it, Windows 7 UAC dialog popping out, I press "Yes", but CopyFile() returning "Access Denied" error.
What is wrong? What should I check?

My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
   <v3:trustInfo xmlns:v3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
     <v3:security>
       <v3:requestedPrivileges>
         <v3:requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
       </v3:requestedPrivileges>
     </v3:security>
   </v3:trustInfo>
 </assembly>
```

My piece of C code:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    if (CopyFile ("aaa.sys", "C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers", FALSE)==FALSE)
        ErrorExit ("CopyFile");
```

Comment: Are you trying to overwrite a MS file owned by TrustedInstaller? Or something that is in use?

Comment: No, I'm writing a file which is not exist there before

Comment: Since you say you see the UAC dialog, answers about whether or not your manifest is correct or correctly attached are misdirected. You are elevating.

Comment: Kate, why CopyFile failed then?

Comment: What does GetLastError() return?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, not really sure what "highestAvailable" does.  Remove all doubt and use "requireAdministrator" instead, that always works to get full admin privileges.  Also make sure you use the right resource name and ID, RT_MANIFEST and 1.

Comment: I attach manifest by running: mt -manifest 1.manifest -outputresource:1.exe;1

Comment: Post the manifest content, what kind of OS, details of the user account and the rights it has in the directory.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <v3:trustInfo xmlns:v3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <v3:security>
      <v3:requestedPrivileges>
        <v3:requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
      </v3:requestedPrivileges>
    </v3:security>
  </v3:trustInfo>
</assembly>

Comment: int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
 if (CopyFile ("aaa.sys", "C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers", FALSE)==FALSE)

Comment: Put it in your question.  This answer will self-destruct in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

- requireAdministrator = Always require admin elevation.
- highestAvailable = If member of admin group, elevate. If normal user, run as normal user without elevation.